# Passing method variables as parameters for code optimization

Tags: c#, design-patterns, optimization

I have a method

```
protected List<string> WrapInTwoLines(string text, int lineLimit)
        {
            ///There will be always two lines even first line can be empty and whole data goes to 2nd line
            string[] originalLines = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();

            StringBuilder actualLine = new StringBuilder();

            int index=0;
            while(actualLine.Length + originalLines[index].Length < lineLimit)
            {
                actualLine.AppendFormat("{0} ",originalLines[index]);
                index++;
            }
            wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());
            actualLine.Clear();

            while (index < originalLines.Length)
            {
                actualLine.AppendFormat("{0} ",originalLines[index++]);
            }
            wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString().TrimEnd(' '));
            return wrappedLines;
        }
```

being called from inside a loop

```
for(int i=0; i< items.Count; i++)
{
    length += items[i].Length + 2;
    if (length > CHAR_LENGTH)
    {
        var list = WrapInTwoLines(items[i], CHAR_LENGTH - (length - items[i].Length + 2));
        subtitlesList.Add(s.Append(list[0]).ToString());

        s = new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("{0}{1}",list[1],separator);
        length = s.Length;
    }
    else
    {
        s.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", items[i], separator);
    }
}
```

My method creates three reference variable with new on each iteration. I was working on optimization of this code and planning to implement the method as follows

```
protected List<string> WrapInTwoLines(string[] originalLines, int lineLimit, List<string> wrappedLines, StringBuilder actualLine)
            {
                ///There will be always two lines even first line can be empty and whole data goes to 2nd line
                //string[] originalLines = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                //List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();
wrappedLines.Clear();

                //StringBuilder actualLine = new StringBuilder();
actualLine.Clear();
    //Rest remains the same
    }
```

I think it will improve the code but I am not sure how much it will improve or will it improve the code or not. What are the tools/techniques I can use to compare the code optimization in terms of memory or speed?
Another question is that is this a good pattern to pass method variables  as parameters(as in above method actualLine etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change will not improve performance significantly.  The garbage collectors for Java and C# are optimized to perform very well in collecting small short-lived objects like your wrappedLines and actualLine.  When you clear wrappedLines instead of creating a new one, the GC still has to collect all the strings that were contained in wrappedLines.

Unless you are having performance problems, don't complicate your code by guessing at performance optimizations.  The WrapInTwoLines method is easier to understand and less error-prone without the extra parameters.

If you are having performance problems, look first inside the innermost loops - this is the code that gets executed most often.  AppendFormat requires run-time parsing of the format string - this will perform much worse than Append(" ").Append(originalLines[i]).

As far as tools go, I've had best results just running the problem code multiple times and timing it.  There are more sophisticated tools available but I haven't found much value in them.  Always run multiple timing trials and average them as a single trial may be skewed.